# Salesforce.com Trigger- Require primary contact to save opportunity

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex-code

There are currently two AppExchange apps that do this, but I was wondering if anyone has figured out how to do this without installing an app, as the number of apps I can install in my organization is limited.

The trigger needs to check to see if there is a contact listed, if not, then an error message should display. I tried this with validation rules, but had no luck because the OpportunityContactRole is a separate object.

Could someone provide their thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
trigger OpportunityBeforUpdate on Opportunity (before update) {
   set<Id> oppIdSet = new set<Id>();
   set<Id> OpportunityContactRoleIdSet = new set<Id>();
   for(Opportunity opp:trigger.new){
  if("Some condition")oppIdSet.add(opp.Id);
   }
 for(OpportunityContactRole ocr:[select Id,OpportunityId from OpportunityContactRole                                        where OpportunityId in:oppIdSet]){
OpportunityContactRoleIdSet.add(ocr.OpportunityId);
   }
  for(Opportunity opp:trigger.new){
if(oppIdSet.contains(opp.Id) && !OpportunityContactRoleIdSet.contains(opp.Id))
    opp.addError('Some error'); 
  }
```

}

Comment: `[select Id,OpportunityId from OpportunityContactRole where OpportunityId in:oppIdSet AND IsPrimary=true]` ;)